Video Compression Failed Error in Flutter – How to Fix?
I'm working on a Flutter project where I need to compress videos, but I'm encountering an error:
i'm using video compression plus version 1.0.0
I/flutter (27379): Video compression failed after 3 attempts.
I/flutter (27379): Error uploading video: Exception: Video compression failed after multiple attempts.
V/OppoMediaMetadataRetriever(27379): closeFd()
What could be causing the video compression to fail and return null? How can I resolve this issue and successfully compress and upload videos in my Flutter app?

Where are the videos from? What is the logcat? Android has a limited set of supported formats: https://developer.android.com/media/platform/supported-formats so random video file from the internet may not work.

i'm using supported format video but still experiencing this issue

Edit your post with logcat messages around failure.

you can use pub.dev plugin video_compress: 3.1.3 for video compress.

We certainly can do nothing unless you post the log in detail.
Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78877997/8322843, hope it will help.
